# Do not open Website

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I use open-cart to build e-commerce web. When I enter url: http://supersmartstyles.com/ it will take too much time and it is not open.

when I put http_server on "config.php" page it not open when i remove that then its open with error

Notice: Use of undefined constant HTTP_SERVER - assumed 'HTTP_SERVER' in /home/stylesmart/public_html/index.php on line 63

Notice: Use of undefined constant HTTPS_SERVER - assumed 'HTTPS_SERVER' in /home/stylesmart/public_html/index.php on line 64

If anybody have any idea about this, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can be database slowdown, but can also be a misconfiguring Apache or Nginx.